# How to get a file size in Bytes or in MB's through a URL

Tags: java, file-io, content-length, http-content-length

I am new to Java.. I was trying to get the file size from a URL but I failed can any one help me how to get the URL size in bytes?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you want to do with it? Which libraries do you use? More info please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`getContentLength`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) method of the [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) which is obtained from [`URL#openConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29)

Comment: Just remember, not all URLs will return a length, ts will come down to what the server returns

Answer (score 2):

```
    File file =new File("xxxxx"); // file path

    if(file.exists()){
        double bytes = file.length();
        double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
        System.out.println("bytes : " + bytes);
        double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
        System.out.println("kilobytes : " + kilobytes);
        double gigabytes = (megabytes / 1024);
        System.out.println("megabytes : " + megabytes);
        double terabytes = (gigabytes / 1024);
        System.out.println("gigabytes : " + gigabytes);
        double petabytes = (terabytes / 1024);
    }else{
         System.out.println("File does not exists!");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to say, that has nothing to do with URL

Comment: Sorry i just misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getFileSizeInBytes(String path){
try {
        URL url=new URL(path);
        URLConnection urlConnection=url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        int file_size=urlConnection.getContentLength();
        return  file_size;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    }catch (IOException e){

    }
    return -1;
}
```